# Docker Container works locally but fails on server

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm fairly new to docker and I'm kind of experimenting with Angular CLI app. I managed to run it locally through my docker container. It works great, but when I try running it from my server it fails.

Server is hosted on DigitalOcean:

```
512 MB Memory / 20 GB Disk / FRA1 - Ubuntu Docker 17.03.0-ce on 14.04
```

I used dockerhub to transfer my container to the server.

When logging the container it gives me this:

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:4200. **
 63% building modules 469/527 modules 58 active ...s/@angular/compiler/src/assertions.jsKilled

npm info lifecycle angular-test@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-test@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-test@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve --host 0.0.0.0'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-test
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How come it runs locally and fails on server? Am I missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

ng serve is an angular-cli command. I'm guessing you need to install it globally in your docker file if you want to start your server like that on digital ocean:

```
RUN npm i -g angular-cli
```

I think it would be more typical to simply run the app using the naked node server in production.  So your CMD would look more like this:

```
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```